# Why does joint distribution of simulation output and functionality output is required?

Tags: multiparty-computation, simulation

I was going through this [simulation](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046) tutorial.

> For example, let x and y be lists of data elements, and
> let f be a functionality that outputs an independent random sample of **x ∪ y** of some predetermined
> size to each party. Now, consider a protocol that securely outputs the **same random sample to
> both parties** (and where each party’s view can be simulated). Clearly, this protocol should **not** be
> secure. In particular, party P1 should have no information about the sample received by P2, and
> vice versa.

Followed by this, there is this definition of simulation which makes this "insecure" protocol secure
[image]

My doubts are the following:

1. Even if we consider the joint distribution definition (mentioned below), the
   [image]
   probabilistic function `f(x, y)` (in the above example text) is same as the `output(x, y, n)` and (it is available to simulator since it is **well defined** in case of **semi honest adversaries**), then how would this definition prevent the above "insecure" protocol example from being secure?
2. How does the output of S1 becomes distinguishable from the real world if the adversary1 which is aware of above insecure protocol knows `f2(x, y)` ? Isn't this known even in the real world scenario? How is it that the simulator is learning something extra other than the real world execution?

P.S Any useful resources to understand the theory of automata notations used in this tutorial would be of great help.